# WCF service start operation method from same service instance

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a service with a simple contract like a:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculateMethods
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Calculate(Parameters serviceParams);
}
```

My task is start "Calculate" method not from the Client, but from a ICalculateMethods service instance. Maybe on a timer or Shedule etc. Other words start this method at some specific time of some event, without any outer calls (no client or other services). Call it from some inner loop I suppose, but call it as WFC servive OperationContext if its possible.

Maybe I am miss some WCF trick or something. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information about what you tried so far, e.g. how you called this Interface. What is exactly your question ?

Comment: Then what's the point in having it as service if it's not invokable by client?

Comment: I have a standart WCF client - service relations. Client calls "Calculate" method on Service. My question is, call a "Calculate" method on service from this service itself. Call a service method from service. But with OperationContext.Current not null.

Comment: The point has it functionality is able to start automatic calculations. And be able to start manualy calculations from client.

Comment: In other words: You want the Service to execute some calculation based on a predefined time schedule in addition to explicit client requests to do so. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct.